# PowerShell Start-Job not running a Scriptblock

Tags: powershell

I have been struggling for a few days now with running Start-Job with a -Scriptblock.

If I run this, I get today's date back in Receive-Job:

```
$sb = {Get-Date}
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb
```

Now, I have a script which does some reporting via 65+ API calls for 8 different statuses. In total, it does 500+ API calls and takes almost 20mins to complete (2-5seconds per API call, x 500), so I am looking to run each foreach block in parallel.

The script works well as a script but not as a Start-Job.

The Scriptblock will get a session token, gets data from API server in a foreach loop and then populates the results into a $Global: variable as it goes.

When I run the job, it "Completes" instantly and Has More Data is False (so I can't see any error messages):

```
67     Job67           BackgroundJob   Completed     False           localhost            foreach ($item....
```

Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong?

My sample code looks like this:

```
$sb = {# Get count of Status1
            foreach ($item in $Global:GetItems) {
                $item1 = $item.id
        
                If ($null -eq $TokenExpiresIn) { .\Get-Token.ps1 }
                $Global:TokenExpiresIn = New-TimeSpan -Start $TokenExpiresNow -End $Script:TokenExpiresTime
        
                $Method = "GET"
                $Fromitems = $item1
                $Status = "foo"
                $Limit = "1"
                $Fields = "blah"
                    
                $URL = "https://$APIServer/apis/v1.1/status?customerId=1&itemId=$Fromitems&status=$Status&fields=$Fields&limit=$Limit"
                $Header = @{"Accept" = "*/*"; "Authorization" = "Bearer $SessionToken" }
        
                $itemStatsResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Method $Method -Uri $URL -Header $Header
                $itemStatsJSON = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $itemStatsResponse 
                $itemCount = $itemStatsJSON.metadata.count
        
                $Global:GetItems | Where-Object -Property id -EQ $item1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty "foo" -Value $itemCount
            }
}
```

I am running the Scriptblock as follows:

```
Start-Job -Name "foo" -ScriptBlock $sb
```

I am using PowerShell 7.1. The script as a whole runs successfully through all 500+ API calls, however it's a bit slow, so I am also looking at how I can "milti-thread" my API calls moving forward for better performance.

Thanks in advance for your support/input. The other posts on StackOverflow relating to PowerShell and Scriptblocks have not assisted me thus far.

Comment: Where are variables `$SessionToken`, `$TokenExpiresNow` and `$TokenExpiresIn` defined?

Comment: Hi @Theo, $SessionToken, $TokenExpiresNow and $TokenExpiresIn comes from the .\Get-Token.ps1 script.

Comment: Aha, that is vital information you didn't show in the question. Try using those values with the script (or global or using) scope in the scriptblock, otherwise they are unknown variables. `$TokenExpiresNow` --> `$script:TokenExpiresNow` etc. Do that on **all** occurrences of the variables. You do that ony sometimes now..